# Use Local ODBC Connection in .NET Application?

Tags: .net, connection, odbc

Hopefully this is an easy one...  I'm just starting an application and I'd like to use one of the ODBC connections specified under Data Sources in the Administrative Tools section of the Control Panel in Windows.

How would I go about setting up a database connection to use those details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as setting the connection string as:

"Dsn=DsnName; Uid=UserName;Pwd=Password;"

So in code..

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=DsnName; Uid=UserName;Pwd=Password;");
```